# Different methods to solving a sequence problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is a question from Manhattan Prep GRE book, and here is the question.

> If each number in a sequence is three more than the previous number, and the sixth number is $32$, what is the 100th number?

what is the sequence rule to this problem. While the book finds the solution differently. I would like to know what the sequence rule is.

This is solution Manhattan Prep provided.

> $100 - 6 = 94$ terms. $94 *3 = 282$.
>
> $32 + 282 = 314$ . One hundredth term $ = 314$ .

Comment: The sequence is $a,a+3, a+6, \ldots , a+3(n-1), \ldots$. The sixth term is $a+15$. So $a=17$. Hope you get the idea. This is what is called an arithmetic progression.

Comment: Thank you @AnuragA. This helps a lot.

Comment: @AnuragA So to find the 100th term is it a(100th) = 17 + 3(100 - 1) = 314.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

$$a_6=32$$
$$a_7=32+3(7-6)$$
$$a_8=32+3(8-6)$$
$$a_{100}=32+3(100-...)$$